# am I good enough to apply for a junior job?

Tags: entry-level, junior

I studied programming as a c# developer, we were using ADO.NET and SQL-Server also we studied ASP.NET, I took my degree with a very honorable mark
I wrote many freelancing software by my own(all hand coded) but I don't feel like it's so professional and errors free, for that i don't really apply for  jobs here since i never worked in a real company
how can i know in which level am I? because compared to engineers here I'm really almost nothing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because We cannot judge your qualifications from a blurb you posted here.

Comment: We all start somewhere. I'm self  taught and have had 3 development jobs. I've no degree, no development qualifications (just the standard GCSE ones that they dish out for free at high school) but I've now 10 years experience and I still learn something new every day.

Comment: Career advice questions are off topic here, voting to close.

Comment: That's point of a junior position--its really entry level out of college. Junior implies you are still in the learning stages.

Comment: As an occasional interviewer, I constantly see university graduates that cannot code anything, so I think you should absolutely not worry about it, given your practical experience and knowledge.

Comment: How can you measure your level of knowledge if you do not come to an interview?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/111883/1996

Comment: Fear nothing, jr are supposed to not know everything and do a lot of errors. That's why they are underpaid (a lot more than seniors)

Answer (score 5):

You can definitely apply for a junior position, they will not expect your code to be perfect. The most important thing is that you get out there and work in different positions so you can see where your ability is at.

I was in a similar position, I thought I would be terrible at my job being a graduate with no work experience, but it turns out I am much better than I thought. It is common for high achievers to have '[Impostor Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome)' where you don't think you are good enough and that when you do do well it is a fluke.

Comment: maybe you're right, I always try to compare myself with the best out there which makes me think I'm so bad for even a normal level, I even got 1st prize of a software competition but I thought I only won it because I live in a country with bad competitors
thank you man..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at the right company. A junior job can mean different things at a company with 40 people than one with 1000 people. For some places it is the same as entry level.

For any job you're applying for, carefully read the description and decide if you can do that work. If you can, you are a good fit for application. If you can't, but feel that you would be able to with some additional work, perhaps apply anyway and say so in your cover letter.

Or, if you find there is a set of skills that often disqualifies you from applying, perhaps obtain those skills.

Comment: I wouldn't decide based on a job specification. Most of them are highly speculative and even those that aren't are asking for more than most candidates have. If you think you've got 60-70% then go for it and unless you think you're missing a  major skill there's no point in mentioning it in the cover letter.

Comment: Right. That is what I meant by job description and not requirements. The requirements are often ridiculous. "Janitor: must have 10 years experience and a Masters degree."